# Vyper Equivalent for solidity's address(this)

Tags: smartcontracts, vyper

How to get the address of current contract in Vyper. In solidity `address(this)` is used. What is the equivalent in Vyper.

```
address myContractAddress;
myContractAddress = address(this);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just `self`, as in:

```py
@public
def get_address() -> address:
    return self
```